When I try to download spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.0.0, I receive a message
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10.0.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.0.0].
    - spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10.0.0 requires illuminate/bus ^9.0 -> found illuminate/bus[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "astrotomic/laravel-translatable": "^11.13",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.29",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}

I followed these steps:

delete composer.lock
composer update
composer require "spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.0.0"

laravel version 10

You have Laravel 10, but the version you are using is for Laravel 9... I have no idea why it is not trying to use latest 10.x version, but use this command instead: composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.7.9

Problem 1
- maennchen/zipstream-php[2.0.0, ..., 2.4.0] require psr/http-message ^1.0 -> found psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10.7.9 requires maennchen/zipstream-php ^2.0 -> satisfiable by maennchen/zipstream-php[2.0.0, ..., 2.4.0].
- Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10.7.9 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.7.9].

The issue has been resolved by using this command:
composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.15

